# django call related model queryset like rails activerecord merge scope

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, orm

Say we have two models Account and Profile:

```ruby
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :account
    scope :age_upper, ->(age) { where("age > ?", age) }
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :profile
end
```

Then we can have a query on Account model in Rails like this:

```ruby
>>> Account.joins(:profile).merge(Profile.age_upper(18))
```

But with Django:

```python
class ProfileQuerySet(models.QuertSet):
    def age_upper(age):
        return self.filter(age__gt=age)

class Profile(models.Model):
    account = models.ForiegnKey('Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = models.Manager.from_queryset(ProfileQuerySet)()


class Account(models.Model):
    pass
```

My question is can we query from Account using filter `age_upper` of Profile instead of rewrite another one for Account like below

```python
class AccountQuerySet(models.QuertSet):
    def age_upper(age):
        return self.filter(profile__age__gt=age)

class Account(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager.from_queryset(AccountQuerySet)()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you can't use a scope of one model to query another (at least with ActiveRecord). And even if you would find the way to do this that's probably not the best way to accomplish this.

If you don't want to write scopes or other shared logic again you can use concerns like that:

```
# app/models/concerns/shared_scopes.rb
module SharedScopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :age_upper, ->(age) { where("age > ?", age) }
  end
end
```

And then include this concern in all model where you need this behavior:

```
# app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  include SharedScopes
  belongs_to :account
end

# app/models/account.rb
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  include SharedScopes
  has_one :profile
end
```

Comment: maybe you misunderstood my question, I mean I want to perform rails-like query in django. And btw, in your answer, if I do `Account.age_upper(18)`, it will fire error because `Account` does not have `age` attribute

Comment: Indeed, this is ruby code and he's asking for python code. Also, he's right that yes you can "use a scope of one model to query another" in ActiveRecord and the OP demonstrated how.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like below.

```
Account.objects.filter(profile_set__id__in=Profile.objects.age_upper(18).only('id'))
```